# Play framework - Writes partial object

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0

I have the following object:

```
case class A(id: Long, name:String, lastName:Option[String], age:Int)
```

I want to use Writes convertor to write only part of this object.
So I tried this code (trying to write the object without the age):

```
implicit val aWrites: Writes[A] = (
  (JsPath \ "it").write[Long] and
  (JsPath \ "name").write[String] and 
  (JsPath \ "lastName"). writeNullable[String]
)(unlift(A.unapply))
```

But this obviously doesn't compile.
Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: what are you trying to do there? `Writes` will look at `case` class at compile time that you want to write `Writes` for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this, but you can't reference `A.unapply`. Part of the conciseness of JSON combinators comes from the `apply` and `unapply` methods that are automatically generated by the compiler for case classes. But these methods use *all* of the parameters in the class.

`A.unapply` has the signature `A => Option[(Long, String, Option[String], Int)]`. This is incompatible with combinators that only cover three fields (instead of all four). You have two options.

1) Write another `unapply`-like method that has the correct signature:

```
def unapplyShort(a: A): Option[(Long, String, Option[String], Int)] =
    Some((a.id, a.name, a.lastName))

implicit val aWrites: Writes[A] = (
  (JsPath \ "id").write[Long] and
  (JsPath \ "name").write[String] and 
  (JsPath \ "lastName").writeNullable[String]
)(unlift(unapplyShort))
```

2) Manually create the `Writes` as an anonymous class:

```
implicit val aWrites: Writes[A] = new Writes[A] {
  def writes(a: A): JsValue = Json.obj(
    "id" -> a.id,
    "name" -> a.name,
    "lastName" -> a.lastName
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Option 1) from @m-z can be put more succinctly as:

```
implicit val aWrites: Writes[A] = (
  (JsPath \ "id").write[Long] and
  (JsPath \ "name").write[String] and
  (JsPath \ "lastName").writeNullable[String]
)((a) => (a.id, a.name, a.lastName))
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI, you can achieve that like the following. (This is just a suggestion.)

```
object noWrites extends OWrites[Any] {
  override def writes(o: Any): JsObject = JsObject(Seq())
}

implicit val aWrites: Writes[A] = (
  (JsPath \ "id").write[Long] and
  (JsPath \ "name").write[String] and
  (JsPath \ "lastName").writeNullable[String] and noWrites // <---
)(unlift(A.unapply))
```